# Using Flask-CORS with Flask LoginManager

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-cors

My flask back-end authentication is using Flask LoginManager to handle users login and logout.

The LoginManager is session based auth and i'm having a lot of troubles in JavaScript front-end with the views which are using @login_required decorator.
When i remove this decorator my front-end works correctly.

I searched and fined out i should use CORS in my back-end.

Now my question is how can i user Flask-CORS with login_required and flask LoginManager?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
app = Blueprint('app', __name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)


@login_required
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def my_view():
    ... #returns some jsonify values
```

Could anyone helps me ?

Comment: If you could please specify the particular errors, ```I'm having a lot of troubles in JavaScript front-end with the views which are using @login_required decorator```
It will be easy for us to debug the issue ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Yes and I'll share my answer in this post in a few days. But my solution doesn't work when front-end (js) and back-end (flask) are on different systems. They just work in a single server.

Comment: Could you share your solution?

Comment: @RamtinMousavi can you share your solution?(this came in later sry)